# What instances drop Pets?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Lately i found myself running a lot of old instances, for fun, farming professions, reputation, or the one or other special drop. I also got more interested in the pet battle system, which i find quite fun. Now I would like to know in which instances i might get battlepets as loot.
I already know of some:

- Wailing Caverns: the Deviate Hatchling drops from the raptors. I found this accidentally while farming leather
- Magisters' Terrace: The Phoenix Hatchling drops from Kael'thas. As far as i know in normal mode as well as on heroic.
- The classic Raid Instances: see [Raiding with Leashes](http://www.wowhead.com/achievement=7934)
- Some BC raids: see [Raiding with Leashes II: Attunement Edition](http://www.wowhead.com/achievement=8293)
- Several current Pandaria raids. I don't know the specifics on these, since i do not raid.

Are there any others?

Comment: There are a lot... Set filter to Drop or Raid Drop on this page: http://www.warcraftpets.com/wow-pets/filter/

Answer (score 1):

There are also 2 pet drops in Lower blackrock spire:

- http://www.wowhead.com/item=68673
- http://www.wowhead.com/item=12264

And if you go on wowhead you can search for allot more :)